# How can I make my pandas DataFrame loop more efficient when trying to append to a list

Tags: python, pandas

This loop currently takes 15+ minutes to run. Are there any tools or ideas on how I can improve the speed of this? There are about 75K rows to iterate through.

I did try appending it directly into the dataframe instead of using the list, the performance was the same.

I'm basically trying to turn every date in the dataframe to the first of the month. ie 2021-01-19 would turn into 2021-01-01

```
fiscal_list = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    clean_date = df['Original Due Date'].str[:8].iloc[1] + "01"
    fiscal_list.append(clean_date) 
df['fiscal_list'] = fiscal_list
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pd.offsets.MonthBegin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#anchored-offset-semantics):

```
df["fiscal_list"] = df["Original Due Date"] + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be faster:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['date'] -= pd.DateOffset(days=1) * (df.date.dt.day - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just doing this

```
df['Original Due Date'] = df['Original Due Date'].str[:8] + "01"
```

Took .05 seconds to run!

Thanks for everyone who answered

Comment: Note that this way gives you strings as output, whilst the other two answers give you Timestamps.

Comment: Good point, I didn't realize that. That may become useful. Thank you!